# Cannot click on Link

Tags: html, css

I Have a problem regarding the clicking on a link within a picture. As you can see in the code, I got some icons for facebook, twitter and youtube on my page and I want to link them to the orginal soure. But if I am trying to click on the link it is not working.

I am struggling some time with this problem, can anyone help me out please.

```
<div id="content">
<div id="social_media">
    <img  id='audio_img' src="img/fb.png" href="https://www.facebook.com 
    /fcbarcelona" alt='Facebook' title='Facebook' width='35' height='35'>
    <img  id='audio_img' src="img/twiiter.png" href="https://twitter.com
    /FCBarcelona" alt='Twitter' title='Twitter' width='35' height='35'>
    <img  id='audio_img' src="img/yt.png" href="https://www.youtube.com
    /fcbarcelona" alt='Youtube' title='Youtube' width='35' height='35'>
</div>

#social_media{
 position:fixed;
 margin-left:18px;
 margin-top:43px;
  }

 #social_media img {
 display: block; 
 margin-top:5px;
 }
```

Comment: there are no links (`<a>`) only images (`<img>`)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the whole image a link by putting a /a around it

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/fcbarcelona">
    <img  id='audio_img' src="img/fb.png" alt='Facebook' title='Facebook'width='35' height='35'>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/fcbarcelona">
 <img  id='audio_img' src="img/fb.png"> alt='Facebook' title='Facebook' width='35' height='35'> </a>
```

Comment: What are you trying to say here? This looks like you copied user6480540's answer, but added a critical syntax error (the `>` before `alt='Facebook'`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use just a element without image one:

```
CSS:
a{text-decoration: none;}
.fb{background-image: url('fb.png') no-repeat; background-size: 35px 35px;}
.yt{background-image: url('yt.png') no-repeat; background-size: 35px 35px;}
.tw{background-image: url('tw.png') no-repeat; background-size: 35px 35px;}
HTML:
<a class="fb"></a>
<a class="tw"></a>
<a class="yt"></a>
```